# Cannot type in cell after setting DataGridView.CurrentCell

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a bound DataGridView in which I've set a DateTimePicker control to become accessible when I click in the first column of a row. This works well.

My problem is when I exit the DateTimePicker cell and the DataGridView is repopulated the active cell always becomes the top left in the grid. To remedy this, I store the current Column and Row indexes then set the CurrentCell:

```
int iColumn = e.ColumnIndex;
int iRow = e.RowIndex;
dgvDataGrid.CurrentCell = dgvDataGrid[iColumn + 1, iRow];
```

I tried including

```
dgvDataGrid.CurrentCell.Selected = true;
```

And

```
dgvDataGrid.BeginEdit(true);
```

But it seems no matter what I try I cannot begin entering data into the Selected cell unless I actually click in that cell first. I have checked, the iColumn and iRow values are what I expect/want them to be.

My goal is to set the CurrentCell then be able to enter data into it with out having to click the cell first.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `dgvDataGrid.BeginEdit(true);` … should allow the user to start typing into the cell without clicking on the cell. There must be something else going on. Where is this line of code executed?

Comment: @JohnG, in the CellValueChanged event handler, immediately after the DB is updated and the grid is repopulated.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. If the code that is not working is in the grids `CellValueChanged` event, then is there some reason you did not post this code? Setting the grids `BeginEdit` is not going to accomplish anything if you call it “inside” the grids `CellValueChanged` event. In addition, this seems to be tied to a `DateTimePicker` cell and repopulating the grid? How is the date time picker set to work with a particular cell? Obviously if you repopulate the grid, then the current cell will become the top-left cell.

Comment: I suggest you show an example of what you are trying to do and what is not working. Currently your question is not clear and the small amount of posted code is no help in understanding what you are trying to do. Creating a full [mre] will increase your chances of getting an answer instead of more questions. Good Luck.

Comment: @JohnG, Thank you for your input and insight. I do appreciate your time and help, but I've decided to approach the problem from another direction. Thank you again!